# Simple feed forward neural network on Tensorflow question

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, tensorflow

I'm building a simple feedforward neural network in Tensorflow and something seems to be broken.  I have adopted the basic structure from http://joelgrus.com/2016/05/23/fizz-buzz-in-tensorflow/ and have tried to adapt it to spit out 1 output unit instead.  The input is 10 numerically represented players ex:(5, 17, 19, 54, 110, 3, 112, 78, 60, 63), 5 on the 'North' team and 5 on the 'South' team, and the output is a 1 or 0 (if the 'North' team won or not).  3 hidden layers (200 parameters each).  With how this is set up, the algorithm trains to constantly predict 1 (North victory).  What can I fix that allows this to train to predict which team is going to have a higher chance of winning?  My expected outcome is ex: [.54] (slight edge to the north team) or [.40] (edge to the south team) etc.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import sqlite3

def get_matches(start, stop):
    connection = sqlite3.connect('5v5.db')
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    result = cursor.execute('''SELECT * FROM matches WHERE rowid>=? AND rowid<=?''', (start, stop))

    return result.fetchall()

def init_weights(shape):
    return tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape, stddev=0.01))

def model(X, w_h1, w_h2, w_h3, w_o):
    h1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(X, w_h1))
    h2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(h1, w_h2))
    h3 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(h2, w_h3))
    return tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(h3, w_o))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TRAINING_GAMES = 2500 #number of games to train on
    TEST_GAMES = 500 #number of games to test the results on

    NUM_DIGITS = 10 #input units
    FIRST_HIDDEN_LAYER = 200
    SECOND_HIDDEN_LAYER = 200
    THIRD_HIDDEN_LAYER = 200
    BATCH_SIZE = 150

    training_matches = get_matches(1, TRAINING_GAMES)
    trX = np.array([match[1:11] for match in training_matches])
    trY = np.array([[match[11]] for match in training_matches])

    X = tf.placeholder("float")
    Y = tf.placeholder("float")

    w_h1 = init_weights([NUM_DIGITS, FIRST_HIDDEN_LAYER])
    w_h2 = init_weights([FIRST_HIDDEN_LAYER, SECOND_HIDDEN_LAYER])
    w_h3 = init_weights([SECOND_HIDDEN_LAYER, THIRD_HIDDEN_LAYER])
    w_o = init_weights([THIRD_HIDDEN_LAYER, 1])

    py_x = model(X, w_h1, w_h2, w_h3, w_o)

    cost = tf.square(Y - py_x)
    train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.05).minimize(cost)

    predict_op = py_x

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        tf.initialize_all_variables().run()

        for epoch in range(10000):
            p = np.random.permutation(range(len(trX)))
            trX, trY = trX[p], trY[p]

            for start in range(0, len(trX), BATCH_SIZE):
                end = start + BATCH_SIZE
                sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: trX[start:end], Y: trY[start:end]})

                print(epoch, sess.run(predict_op, feed_dict={X: trX, Y:trY}))

        test_matches = get_matches(TRAINING_GAMES+1, TRAINING_GAMES+TEST_GAMES)

        teX = np.array([match[1:11] for match in test_matches])
        teY = sess.run(predict_op, feed_dict={X: teX})
        print(teY)
```